# Linker error compiling DX10 program in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, directx

I am trying to compile old program which works with DirectX 10. Full list of libraries used:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d10.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx10.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxerr.lib")
#pragma comment( lib, "dxguid.lib" )
```

Linker error:

> dxerr.lib(dxerrw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vsnwprintf referenced in function "long __cdecl StringVPrintfWorkerW(unsigned short *,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64 *,unsigned short const *,char *)" (?StringVPrintfWorkerW@@YAJPEAG_KPEA_KPEBGPEAD@Z)

Comment: For people looking for better answers, see this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053670/unresolved-external-symbol-vsnprintf-in-dxerr-lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of the [legacy DirectX SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) are you using? Static libraries* from different versions of the Visual C++ compiler are generally not compatible, so my guess is you are using a DirectX SDK that no longer supports VS 2005--I believe the February 2010 DXSDK was the last one that did as the June 2010 DXSDK supported VS 2008 and VS 2010.

You can also try building your own [DXERR](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/24/where-s-dxerr-lib.aspx) or move to a newer version of Visual C++.

- = Import libraries work fine which is why you aren't having problems with `D3D10`, `D3DX10`, and `DXGI`.  `DXGUID` is a static library, but it just contains data segment stuff so it tends to not hit problems with mixed C Runtime versions.

See also [Where is the DirectX SDK (2013 Edition)?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx), [DirectX SDK Tools Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/10/28/directx-sdk-tools-catalog.aspx), [Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx), 
[DirectX SDKs of a certain age](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/08/22/directx-sdk-s-of-a-certain-age.aspx), [DirectX SDK Samples Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx)

Comment: June 2010 version. I excluded dxerr.lib and the project is compiled. Thanks for dxerr replacement.